Call aws bedrock agent
There are converse and converse_stream in boto3 bedrockruntime, but why is there only invoke_agent in bedrock-agent-runtime? Should I just use this? Or is there another way to call the agent? I would like to receive a response in streaming form.
It is possible to call invoke_agent with bedrock-agent-runtime. However, it takes about 3 to 5 seconds to respond. I'm trying to use converse or converse_stream to reduce this part, but I don't see the function in agent-runtime.

There's also invoke_model_with_response_stream().
Boto3 documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/bedrock-runtime/client/invoke_model_with_response_stream.html
Examples using Python and other languages in the AWS code example library: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/bedrock-runtime_example_bedrock-runtime_InvokeModelWithResponseStream_AnthropicClaude_section.html
Having that said, for all text models on Bedrock I recommend converse() or converse_stream() because they provide a strongly typed abstraction of the different model providers' native JSON APIs.
